# Lower Bound for the induced matrix norm $||A||_{\infty,1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The induced matrix norm  $||A||_{\infty,1}$ is defined by $||A||_{\infty,1} = \max_{s\in\{-1;1\}^n}{||As||_1}$

What are the known lower bounds for this norm $||A||_{\infty,1}$ when:

1. $A$ is a real matrix?
2. $A$ is a sign matrix (each entry $a_{i,j}\in\{-1;1\}$)?

*From the comments:*

> So far I have found that calculating it is NP-hard, but have no luck of finding papers talking about bounds for it. This norm shows up in denominator of some fraction which I want to show is bounded from above so I need a lower bound for this norm.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: So far I have found that calculating it is NP-hard, but have no luck of finding papers talking about bounds for it.
This norm shows up in denominator of some fraction which I want to show is bounded from above so I need a lower bound for this norm.

Comment: Do you want to *compute* a lower bound or have a *formula* for it?

Comment: I guess what I need is something similar to [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702722v2.pdf). On the numerator of my fraction one element is ${||A||_2}$ so it might be intersting to find some upper bound also for $\frac{||A||_2}{||A||_{\infty,1}}$